# How to use pandas read_csv to read numbers, dates and strings correctly from a csv file?

Tags: pandas, string, csv, types, numbers

I have a csv file (data.csv) like this:

```
A,B,C,D,E
1.50,2.70,"2,481","1,569",2.15
2020-1-1,2020-1-2,2020-1-3,2020-1-4,2020-1-5
John, Jeff, Ruben, Cath, James
```

I tried to use `df=pd.read_csv("data.csv", thousands=',')` I got df=

```
          A        B        C        D        E
0       1.5      2.7    2,481    1,569     2.15
1  2020-1-1 2020-1-2 2020-1-3 2020-1-4 2020-1-5
2      John     Jeff    Ruben     Cath    James
```

Looks OK but actually all numbers and dates are strings in df, while Excel can read/convert them correctly.

How can we read numbers, dates and strings from a csv file correctly?

Comment: one column usually only have one type, check your column A if contain date and number which is more than two types

Comment: yes, but the actual csv file is in this way, and there are many such csv files.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of handling this would be to read it in normally, taking the transpose and handling it column-wise so like this:

```
DF = read_csv(pth).T
DF
       0         1       2
A   1.50  2020-1-1    John
B   2.70  2020-1-2    Jeff
C  2,481  2020-1-3   Ruben
D  1,569  2020-1-4    Cath
E   2.15  2020-1-5   James

DF[0] = DF[0].str.replace(",","").astype(float)
DF
         0         1       2
A     1.50  2020-1-1    John
B     2.70  2020-1-2    Jeff
C  2481.00  2020-1-3   Ruben
D  1569.00  2020-1-4    Cath
E     2.15  2020-1-5   James
```

Then you also have series (columns) with the correct type:

```
DF[0]
A       1.50
B       2.70
C    2481.00
D    1569.00
E       2.15
Name: 0, dtype: float64  #<<<<< float
```

If you are really hell-bent on keeping the original shape, you could also do it like this:

```
df = read_csv(pth)
df.iloc[0,:] = df.iloc[0,:].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)
df
          A         B         C         D         E
0       1.5       2.7    2481.0    1569.0      2.15
1  2020-1-1  2020-1-2  2020-1-3  2020-1-4  2020-1-5
2      John      Jeff     Ruben      Cath     James
```

then you could do this

```
df.iloc[0,0] + df.iloc[0,2]
2482.5
```

But the row itself would still be an object and not float, which may be a disadvantage at some point:

```
df.iloc[0,:]
A       1.50
B       2.70
C    2481.00
D    1569.00
E       2.15
Name: 0, dtype: object   <<<< object
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the only way to work around until next Panda version solves this defect and works as good as Excel